# How to set image, in ImageView fitting parent, without inflating parent

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I'm new member here and very starter in Javafx so first of all sorry in advance if my question is not well explained. I re-edit my question to try to clarify my point giving a minimal code that you can execute from your side. So here is my issue :
I am struggling with the ImageView component and the image set in the ImageView. The main point is that when I set the image inside the ImageView, I loose the control on the geometry of my panes around. If I execute the same code without setting the image in the ImageView, the size of every panes respect my settings. To clarify my point, here is a minimal code that I have tested from my side and that works.

In the following code, I will comment the line in the controller

```
imgView.setImage(image);
```

because the window displayed without this line gives the good geometry that I expect regarding my settings.

So here is the full code :

The FXML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.MainViewController">
    <children>

     <VBox fx:id="parentVbox" spacing="0">
            <children>
                <HBox fx:id="topHbox">
                </HBox>

                <HBox fx:id="downHbox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">

                    <VBox fx:id="emptyVboxLeft" spacing="0">
                    </VBox>

                    <VBox fx:id="emptyVboxCentral" spacing="0">
                    </VBox>

                    <VBox fx:id="imgVboxRight" spacing="0">
                        <GridPane fx:id = "imgGp" >
                            <VBox fx:id="imgVbox" alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                <HBox fx:id = "imgHbox">
                                    <ImageView fx:id="imgView"/>
                                </HBox>
                            </VBox>
                        </GridPane>

                    </VBox>

                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>



    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
</AnchorPane>
```

The Main :

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(new File("src/sample/MainView.fxml").toURI().toURL());
        primaryStage.setTitle("my issue");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The controller :

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;



public class MainViewController {

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * PANE * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  * */
    @FXML
    public AnchorPane anchorPane;
    @FXML
    public VBox parentVbox;
    @FXML
    public HBox topHbox;
    @FXML
    public HBox downHbox;
    @FXML
    public VBox emptyVboxLeft; 
    @FXML
    public VBox emptyVboxCentral; 
    @FXML
    public VBox imgVboxRight; 




    @FXML
    public GridPane imgGp;
    @FXML
    public VBox imgVbox;
    @FXML
    public HBox imgHbox;

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * COMPONENTS * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  * */
    //Components of Vbox Right
    @FXML public ImageView imgView;


    // geometrical parameters used for resizing
    public final double resizeWidthStageVsScreenSize = 0.5;
    public final double resizeHeightStageVsScreenSize = 0.5;
    public final double sizeVboxVsAnchorPane = 1.0;
    public final double divideValueHboxTopMenuVsVbox = 10.0; 
    public final double divideValueCorpusHboxVsVbox = 10.0/9; 
    public final double divideValueCorpusVboxLeftVsCorpusHbox = 10.0/2;
    public final double divideValueCorpusVboxCentralVsCorpusHbox = 10.0/5; 
    public final double divideValueCorpusVboxRightVsCorpusHbox = 10.0/3;

  /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * geometrical parameters related to and around the image * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    public final double percentBorderRowImgGp = 100.0/5;
    public final double percentBorderColumnImgGp = 100.0/3;
    public final double divideValueHeightCorpusHboxImgVsCorpusVboxImg = 10.0/8;



    public void initialize() throws FileNotFoundException {

        /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * Initialization of the window size * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
        Dimension resolution = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = resolution.getWidth();
        double height = resolution.getHeight();
        double w = width*resizeWidthStageVsScreenSize;  // your window width
        double h = height*resizeHeightStageVsScreenSize;  // your window height
        //Window size preference when app is launched
        anchorPane.setPrefWidth(w);
        anchorPane.setPrefHeight(h);

        
        /* * * * * * * * * * * * Initialization of the geometry * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
        //The parentVbox shall have the size of the anchor pane
        parentVbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty());
        parentVbox.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(anchorPane.heightProperty(), sizeVboxVsAnchorPane));

        //Disposition de la hbox menu relative à la vbox
        topHbox.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(parentVbox.heightProperty(), divideValueHboxTopMenuVsVbox));

        //disposition de la corpus hbox relative à la vbox
        downHbox.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(parentVbox.heightProperty(), divideValueCorpusHboxVsVbox));
        //@CLUES
        downHbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ADD8E6;"); //couleur bleue
        //disposition des 3 vbox relatives à la hbox
        emptyVboxLeft.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(downHbox.widthProperty(), divideValueCorpusVboxLeftVsCorpusHbox));
        //@CLUES
        emptyVboxLeft.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");
        emptyVboxCentral.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(downHbox.widthProperty(), divideValueCorpusVboxCentralVsCorpusHbox));
        //@CLUES
        emptyVboxCentral.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 10 10 5 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");
        imgVboxRight.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(downHbox.widthProperty(), divideValueCorpusVboxRightVsCorpusHbox));
        //@CLUES
        imgVboxRight.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");


        /* * * * * * * * * * * * Initialisation de la disposition des composants internes * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

        //Initialisation des images de couvertures sur la Vbox Right

        //Sizing auto du gridPane de la Vbox right :
        imgGp.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(imgVboxRight.widthProperty(), 1.0));
        imgGp.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(imgVboxRight.heightProperty(), 1.0));
        final int numCols = 3 ;
        final int numRows = 3 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
            if(i==0||i==2) {
                colConst.setPercentWidth(percentBorderColumnImgGp);
            }
            else
            {
                colConst.setPercentWidth(100.0-2* percentBorderColumnImgGp);
            }
            imgGp.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
            if(i==0||i==2) {
                rowConst.setPercentHeight(percentBorderRowImgGp);
            }
            else
            {
                rowConst.setPercentHeight(100.0-2* percentBorderRowImgGp);
            }
            imgGp.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);

        }
        //@CLUES
        imgGp.setGridLinesVisible(true);


        //Sizing the Hbox containing the img regarding the Vbox img in the grid pane :
        imgHbox.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(imgVbox.heightProperty(), divideValueHeightCorpusHboxImgVsCorpusVboxImg));
        //@CLUES
        imgHbox.setStyle(
                        "-fx-border-color: coral;");

        //creating the image object
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("F:\\Documents\\resources\\bibliotheque\\cover.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(stream);
        //Setting image to the image view
        //imgView.setImage(image);
        imgView.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFF00;");
        imgView.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: green;");
        //Setting the image view parameters
       imgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(imgHbox.widthProperty().multiply(0.5)); 
      imgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(imgHbox.heightProperty().multiply(0.5));

imgVbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFF00;");



    }


}
```

So now please, uncomment the line of the controller and add your own image path (search in controller "FileInputStream(" and add your own path) and uncomment the line imgView.setImage(image)).

You might see that only adding the image in the ImageView, the whole geometry is disturbed.

Question 1: why ? How to fix this issue?

Question 2: In the last lines of the controller, I want to bind the imgView to its parent Hbox for instance to set the imgView as half of the size of the Hbox using fitWidthProperty() etc... as you can see in the code. I cannot see directly the imgView component (I tried to do a setStyle on it but doesn't give anything..) but I can see that the image takes half of the image view. But I don't understand this control because if you set the fitWidthProperty or HeightProperty to 1.0 or 0.99 in the binding to the Hbox, you might see that the view is expanding => why and how to tell that I want that my imageView has to be set to fit the Hbox ?

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this problem.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Generally speaking, setting PreserveRatio to "true" and binding both the fitHeight and fitWidth properties is going to be strange.  Bind just one or the other of the dimensions.  Binding image scaling to the width of a container without accounting for the padding in the container using `subtract()`  usually ends up with the container growing to accommodate for the padding, which causes the image to grow, and so on. Finally, you have an HBox inside a VBox inside a GridPane inside a VBox - each container having just one element inside.   Do you need them all?  Surely you can ditch the VBoxes?

Comment: Side note: Use [`javafx.stage.Screen`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html) to get the dimensions of the screen via the JavaFX API.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for your advice. I tried to provide a minimal reproductible example. Hope it will help to understand better my issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener on the stage when resizing the window

```
   primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        bookOfCorpusImgView.setFitHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        bookOfCorpusImgView.setFitWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
   });

    primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        bookOfCorpusImgView.setFitHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        bookOfCorpusImgView.setFitWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
   });
```

and Of course you can edit the new height/width to whatever relatives you want like primaryStage.getHeight()/3